# Python: sharing class variables across threads

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a counter (training_queue) shared among many instances of a class. The class inherits threading.Thread, so it implements a run() method. When I call start(), I expect each thread to increment this counter, so when it reaches a limit no more threads are started. However, none of the threads modifies the variable. Here's the code:

```
class Engine(threading.Thread):

    training_mutex = threading.Semaphore(MAX_TRAIN)
    training_queue = 0
    analysis_mutex = threading.Semaphore(MAX_ANALYSIS)
    analysis_queue = 0
    variable_mutex = threading.Lock()


    def __init__(self, config):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.config = config
        self.deepnet = None
        # prevents engine from doing analysis while training
        self.analyze_lock = threading.Lock()

    def run(self):
        with self.variable_mutex:
            self.training_queue += 1
        print self.training_queue
        with self.training_mutex:
            with self.analyze_lock:
                self.deepnet = self.loadLSTM3Model()
```

I protect the training_queue with a Lock, so it should be thread-safe. How ever, if I print its value its always 1. How does threading affect variable scope in this case?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your understanding of how state is shared between threads is correct. However, you are using instance attribute "training_queue" instead of class attribute "training_queue".

That is, you always set training_queue to 1 for each new object.

For example:

```
import threading

class Engine(threading.Thread):
    training_queue = 0
    print_lock = threading.Lock()

    def __init__(self, config):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        with Engine.print_lock:
            self.training_queue += 1
            print self.training_queue

Engine('a').start()
Engine('b').start()
Engine('c').start()
Engine('d').start()
Engine('e').start()
```

Will return:

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

But:

```
import threading

class Engine(threading.Thread):
    training_queue = 0
    print_lock = threading.Lock()

    def __init__(self, config):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        with Engine.print_lock:
            Engine.training_queue += 1  # <-here
            print self.training_queue

Engine('a').start()
Engine('b').start()
Engine('c').start()
Engine('d').start()
Engine('e').start()
```

Returns:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Note self.training_queue vs Engine.training_queue

btw. I think += in python should be atomic so I wouldn't bother with the lock. However, not the usage of lock for printing to stdout in the example above.

Comment: That was the error, thanks. However, i will keep the locks for the counter; += does not seem to be atomic: [http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe.htm]. One thing: if I was using instance variables for all my Semaphores, how did they get to work? (i achieved the concurrency I wanted with them)

Comment: It's actulally a bit missleading.`+=` is not an atomic operation. It requires three lines of code - `__getattr__` , `variable = variable + 1` and `__setattr__`.